# how to display all post tags for each item in a collection?

Tags: eleventy

In the .eleventy.js file, I created a getFilteredByGlob collection for all .md files in my posts directory.

Then for each item in that collection, I'm writing out values from the front matter of each .md file. This works well, but I'm struggling with the tags for each .md file. Most files have 2 or more tags, and I want to have a for loop write out each tag value seperately for each post.

`{{ item.data.tags }}` will show all tags for a given article in a single string, but when I try something like

```
{% for tag in postTags %}
{{ item.data.tags }}
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

nothing is returned. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your loop. Where does the postTags variable come from? I assume it is the collection?

Anyway, your variable names don't match up. You're using `tag` in the start tag of the for-loop, but `item` inside the loop. Use matching variable names and it should work.

```
{% for item in postTags %}
    {{ item.data.tags }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```